# Regex to find a single dot in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to find a single standing dot in a string with Regex? For example, the user input is:

```
7. + 6.5
```

Is there a way to detect that there's an unnecessary dot in the string by 7 and remove it while not touching the dot in 6.5?

Also, is there a way to detect multiple occurrences of the same operator so the following would be considered as invalid:

```
7 ++++ 5 --- 6
```

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In what way is that dot *unnecessary*? `parseInt("7.", 10) === 7` and `console.log(7. + 3) === 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect multiple occurence of operator the regex can be

```
([^\d\s])\1+
```

repalce the string with `$1`

see the link http://regex101.com/r/lN3wH5/1

```
var re = /([^\d\s])\1+/gm; 
var str = '7 ++++ 5 --- 6 + 5';
var subst = '$1'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

will produce output as

```
7 + 5 - 5 +5
```

The single standing `.` can be matched using a negative positive lookahead `(?! )`

using the regex

`\.(?!\d)`

the matched part can be see at http://regex101.com/r/tC7rO6/1

**EDIT**

To validate the string to contain single operator,

regex : `^\d+(\s*[+-\/*%]\s*\d+)+$`

test : http://regex101.com/r/lN3wH5/3

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't work if there's a space between the operators, like so: var str = '7 ++ ++ 5 -- - 6 + 5';

Comment: If you just want to validate the string, `^\d+(\s*[+-\/*]\s*\d+)+$` can be used. http://regex101.com/r/lN3wH5/2

Answer (score 0):

To check only single dot use this:

```
(?!(\.\d))([\.])
```